# Convert aspx content to pdf

Tags: asp.net

I am using iTextSharp for convert aspx content to pdf . But facing problem for https site where page is secured and can't don lad as pdf. and geting error like
"Internet explorer was not able to open this internet site. The requested site

is either unavailable or cannot be found . Please try again later"

Answer (score 0):

Try ABCpdf.NET. You only have to pass the url of the page.

Answer (score 0):

As Sidharth suggested you could use [ABCpdf](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm) library. Take a look at this SO question that I've posted a possible solution for: [Convert HTML to PDF - Any library for ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677594/convert-html-to-pdf-any-library-for-asp-net/4677666#4677666)

Instead of making a call to `AddImageHtml` you need to call [GetImageUrl](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf7net/source/5-abcpdf6/doc/1-methods/addimageurl.htm):

```
int pageID = doc.AddImageUrl(html, true, 1024, true);
```

The rest of the example should be the same.

Hope this will help you.